# Symfony Form Component Standalone Form Type Extension

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a project using some components from Symfony. Namely Twig, Doctrine, and Form.

I would like to modify all form field types to be able to take a new 'suffix' argument when they are created.  It seems like this is usually simple in the full Symfony stack and could be done by extending the existing form type.  However I'm not sure how to get the form component to load my custom extension when using the Form Component standalone.

Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if I understood your question correctly, what you basically want to do, is add new option to your form builder for given type.

**index.php** - Basically here, we will just create a FormBuilder instance and add one field for testing purpose.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationExtension;


$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->getFormFactory()
    ->createBuilder()
    ->add('test', 'text', array('customAttribute' => true))
    ->getForm()
    ->createView();
```

If we open the browser right now, we will get nice and big error, telling us that **"customAttribute"** is unknown option.

So, let's create custom form type! As you saw I named it **TextCustomType** since I will extends "text" form type.

The Type class:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class TextCustomType extends AbstractTypeExtension {

public function getName() {
    return "text";
}

public function getExtendedType() {
    return "text";
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setOptional( array('customAttribute') );

    $resolver->setDefaults( array('customAttribute' => true) );
}

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
    $view->vars['customAttribute'] = $options['customAttribute'];
}

}
```

Now, we created our custom type, so lets add it to the form factory:

```
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->addTypeExtension( new TextCustomType() ) // once the class is loaded simply pass fresh instance to ->addTypeExtension() method.
    ->getFormFactory()
    ->createBuilder()
    ->add('test', 'text', array('customAttribute' => true))
    ->getForm()
    ->createView();
```

Refresh your browser, and you should be good to go! Hope you got the idea.

*Updated as per OP's suggestion.*

Comment: This is much more complete than my answer.  Could be clearer if you remove your note about require statements, and just removed them yourself.  Also, somehow calling out the specific line of code that accomplishes the solution would be great too.  Took me a sec to understand where in your post the extension would be added to the FormFactory.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple! It was just a matter of looking in the right place. The [FormFactoryBuilder](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactoryBuilderInterface.html) is the key:

```
use Symfony\Form\Component\Form\Forms;

$form = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->addTypeExtension(new MyExtension())
    ->getFormFactory()
    ->create();
```

This `$form` variable now knows about my new 'suffix' property.